# NuxtJS's fetch hook is blocked from running in parallel

Tags: fetch, hook, nuxt.js

I have a question about nuxt's fetch hook.

Reproduction link
https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-lederberg-teq9z?file=/pages/index.vue

First of all, "$route."query": "$fetch" in "watch" hook  is used to make fetch work whenever url changes.

Each time the url changes, the fetch hook runs immediately. However if I design the fetch hook to return async function or Promise, it ignores fetch until the previous fetch hook is finished.

For example, if I quickly change the URL from the default state to the order 1->2->3, only the fetch triggered in 1 works and fetch triggered in 2 and 3 is ignored. It seems like, 2, 3 is ignored since first fetch did not end yet.

Why is it working like this?

Answer (score 0):

found answer in the nuxtjs code [link](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/blob/917adc06184efd55a48123269b659adb288a3341/packages/vue-app/template/mixins/fetch.client.js#L83-L89)

`$fetch` function creates a critical section within the function which prevents `$fetch` function to be ran in parallel

```js
function $fetch() {
  // critical section starts
  if (!this._fetchPromise) {
    this._fetchPromise = $_fetch.call(this)
      .then(() => { delete this._fetchPromise })
      // critical section ends
  }
  return this._fetchPromise
}
```